# update a matplotlib figure from another class

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter, figure

How can I update a matplotlib figure that is a child of a frame in another class in tkinter? Here is where I am stuck.

```
class A():
    def__init__(self, master):
        sframe = Frame(master)
        sframe.pack(side=RIGHT)
        f = Figure(figsize=(3,2), dpi=100)

        a = f.add_subplot(122);
        # initially plots a sine wave 
        t = arange(0.0, 1, 0.01);
        s = sin(2*pi*t);
        a.plot(t,s);

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=sframe)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        # now i create the other object that will call show()
        data_obj = B(sframe)


class B():
    ...
    show(self, frame):
       _wlist = frame.winfo_children()
       for item in _wlist:
           item.clear() # or something like this
       # and then re-plot something or update the current plot
```

Comment: You just need to get a reference to the figure or axes objects.  Beware of talking to the objects from multiple threads, it may not work(but I think that it is related to limitations in the gui frameworks).

Comment: thanks tcaswell, I need a reference to the frame because I need to modify more than one figure in the frame...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to in a way or another retrieve your figure object `f` from show method.

pass f to `B` constructor

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, frame, figure):
        self.figure = figure
    ...
    def show(self, frame):
        ...
        self.figure.plot( something )
```

add f as an attribute of your frame

```
class A:
    def__init__(self, master):
        ...
        sframe.fig = f
        data_obj = B(sframe)
class B:
    def show(self, frame):
        ...
        frame.fig.plot( something )
```

Comment: Thanks @FabianAndre for the suggestions. The problem is that I have more than one figure in the frame, so I need to access a particular figure. That is why I tried winfo_children. However, I can not do much with the child which returns 'Canvas' when I call winfo_class(). I want a way of accessing the figure f associated with this canvas to be able to update what I plotted previously (in this case a sine wave). How can I access the figure to clear/update it?

Comment: I solved it in a similar way. Instead of adding the figure to the frame, I added the axis and also the canvas associated to the figure. So now to update it, I do:  sframe.ax = a and once in show():  sframe.ax.clear()  sframe.ax.plot(newline)  sframe.canvas.show()  Is there a more elegant way of doing this?